# ListView not rendering after a SegmentedBar route

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have started using Nativescript with Angular2 - it's awesome btw.
I have used the nativescript-angular2 List example in the sample folder of the repository (nativescript-angular/ng-sample/app/examples/list/). I can get the component to render the data on my home screen. But when adding the List component into a component that gets routed to using Router (v3) the data doesn't render. It just renders a list of empty items.

Has anyone had the same issue?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have the same issue. This issue is already known to the developers,hope we get a fix soon.

It seems that ngzone fails to start after routing(causing any changes to not be observed)
As a workaround try  importing:

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef,ApplicationRef} from '@angular/core';
```

...

initialize and use :

```
constructor(private _applicationRef: ApplicationRef,private ref:ChangeDetectorRef){

        setTimeout(() => {
            _applicationRef.zone.run(() => _applicationRef.tick())
        }, 100)//request with timeout to start zone

        this.ref.reattach();//reattach the change detector
                            //(i use it whenever there is a change that will change the template)

}
```